# Process.Start returns null

Tags: c#, process

I'm writing a program that launches a random file in s directory. the file can be of any type, but mostly video or image files.
Each time I launch a file I want to close the previous opened one.

Code :

```cs
string FolderSelected = "";
string FileName = "";
Process proc;
            
List<string> FilesDisplayed = new List<string>();

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FolderSelected == string.Empty)
        FolderSelected = Properties.Settings.Default.FilesDefaultFolder;

    if (proc != null)
    {
        proc.CloseMainWindow();
        proc.Close();
    }
    FileName = FetchRandomFile();
    proc = Process.Start(FileName);
}
```

Problem is, that I keep getting `proc = null` (the file is launched properly) and I cannot fetch the previously opened process in order to close it. I know that .NET reuses processes and that's why it returns Null but I need to override this behavior.

Answer (score 16):

EDIT: Thanks to leppie's comment, I suspect I know the answer: my guess is that you're "starting" something like an image, and it's reusing an existing process to open the document instead of creating a new one.

I've reproduced this with this simple test app:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Process proc = Process.Start("image.tif");
        Console.WriteLine(proc == null);
    }
}
```

This prints "true" because it's using `dllhost.exe` to host the Windows Image Viewer, rather than creating a new process.

Comment: `static Process Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)` can return `null`, if the process didn't start (or is already started).

Comment: I need to override this behavior, because i want to close the last opened file before opening a new one.
how can i do this?

Comment: @gash25: I don't *think* you can. You can use a `ProcessStartInfo` with `UseShellExecute` set to false, but I suspect that'll just make it fail to start. If you know which process should be used, you could explicitly start that executable.

Comment: thanks,
But finding out which process is too much of a overhead.
i just need a simple random open and close file program.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem, you have to set `UseShellExecute` to false to bypass the shell.

Instead of

```
Process.Start("filename", "args")
```

use

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() {
    FileName = "filename",
    Arguments = "args",
    UseShellExecute = false
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. I'm getting exception which says that the file is not a correct Win32 application (in my case it's a video file). This works only with executables.

Comment: This will not solve the problem in case `UseShellExecute` will mainly assist to find the application to use the wanted file (like image/pdf/doc/...). If it works with `UseShellExecute = false` it even will also work with `UseShellExecute = true` and respond with a valid process.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring 'proc' at method scope, so of course it will *always* be null when checked at the top of that method.  If you want the reference to live beyond the function, declare it is a class level variable.

You are spawning a process each time (probably), Process.Start is not returning null, but you simply lose the reference to it when i goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

That won't even compile (definite assignment). As a *method variable*, `proc` is local only to the declaring method(/scope) - i.e. `button2_Click`, which explains why you can't retain values. If `proc` is meant to persist between calls, promote it to a *field* (per-instance variable):

```
Process proc;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (proc != null)
    ...
```