# Find process id when Process.Start returns null?

Tags: c#, .net, process

If I try to open an image file, or video, or website by calling `Process.Start(filepath)` directly, then it will typically succeed. However, the return value of Process.Start will sometimes be null. ([As discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456414/1233949))

I need to know the associated process's id so that I can retrieve it later and close it if necessary. (Use case: User opens an image file using my program, and would like to close it using my program) However, it's kind of hard to retrieve the process id of a process that returns null :P

Any suggestions on how I should go about this, other than maybe specifying directly which program to use for each type of file we may encounter?

Comment: What would you want to do if opening the image/video/whatever didn't start a *new* process, but just opened it in an existing one? I'd be pretty miffed if a long-running process which was still useful with *other* files suddenly closed...

Comment: That's not the purpose of this software though. If you're creating an image in this way, it's specifically because you want it opened separate from any other image viewer / process currently running. If you wanted simply to change the image, you could do so directly by interacting with the OS. (Basically, business rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify directly which program to use to get the id of the process.  I can imagine you can ask the os what program to use for each extensions as the os has a list of those.

Comment: Would this depend on Registry Keys? That's all I can seem to find using Google. Otherwise everyone says to just use Process.Start, but they obviously don't need all the same info I do.

EDIT: Found this, which I think might solve it, but will be sorta messy. :( 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/162371/1233949