# When can Process.Start() return null?

Tags: c#, .net, process, system.diagnostics

I have some code that starts a process by using [Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0w4h05yb(v=vs.100).aspx). I see from the documentation that this method can return null if an existing process is reused.

> [Returns a] new Process component that is associated with the process
>   resource, or null if no process resource is started (for example, 
>   **if an existing process is reused**).

What does it mean for an existing process to be reused and under what circumstances will this happen?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456383/process-start-returns-null

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would happen if you call pass a file (not an EXE), and the file is configured to launch using DDE.

For example, this is how Office applications open files in existing instances.

Comment: I wondered if it was something along those lines, so I wrote the following test code:
`var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\test.doc");
var process1 = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
var process2 = Process.Start(processStartInfo);` 
process2 was not null, although just the one instance of the document was opened in a single instance of Word. Is it platform or version dependent?

Comment: I've just tried it with a xlsx file. process2 was null. Thanks.