# C# - Stopping a Forms application on exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I am creating a Windows Forms application in which I need small help for exception handling.

**What my application would do (an overview)**: Take inputs from the user in the start. When the user clicks on the `Finish` button, the inputs are processed. Based on the inputs given, certain computations are performed. After this, an application is uninstalled using `msiexec /x` command (being launched as a separate process).

If there is an exception during the input processing time (that is, before the uninstall task), I am calling the `Application.Exit()` method. Following code snippet might give you an idea:

```
try
{
    //some processing
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    DisplayErrorMessage();
    WriteToLog(exc.Message);
    WriteToLog("Inner Exception: " + exc.InnerException);
    Application.Exit();
}
```

**My Observation:** If any exception was encountered during the processing time, the `Process.Start()` method is returning `null`.

Can somebody tell why this is happening? Is there a way to overcome this?

**P.S:** How do i need to modify my code so that, if an exception occurs previously, the process doesn't even start?

Comment: When do you call `Process.Start()`?

Comment: I'm calling it after the `catch` block execution

Comment: You should add `return` inside `catch` to prevent code after to run.

Comment: Try adding a return after `Application.Exit()`. For process start returning null check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427404/when-can-process-start-return-null

Comment: Or put the Process.Start() inside the Try block

Comment: Adding `return` still resulted in the same behavior! :-( Also  tried putting `Process.Start()` in try block. But still the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that calling `Environment.Exit(1)` actually terminates the forms application, which is not done by calling the `Application.Exit()` method.

More information can be obtained from the following link: [How to properly exit a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977924/how-to-properly-exit-a-c-sharp-application)