Process is null, but it will start the media player or the app needed to open the file
I have a wpf app, that searches in a directory and starts a process, such as opening the media player.
The app starts the media Player, in case of mp3 files, but the process for some reason is null.
Here is my MainViewModel
[ObservableProperty]
string? folderPath;

[ObservableProperty]
FileItem? selectedItem;

[ObservableProperty]
double progress;

[ObservableProperty]
bool isEnable = true;

public ObservableCollection<FileItem> Files { get; set; } = [];

public List<Process>? Processes { get; set; } = [];

[RelayCommand]
async Task CleanFolder()
{
    await DeleteNonMp4files(FolderPath!);
}

[RelayCommand]
void BrowseFolders()
{
    var dlg = new OpenFolderDialog();
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        FolderPath = dlg.FolderName;
        GetFiles(FolderPath);
    }
}

public void GetFiles(string folderPath)
{
    {
        string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var projectRoot = Directory.GetParent(baseDirectory)?.Parent?.Parent?.Parent?.FullName;
        string extensionsIconsFolderPath = Path.Combine(projectRoot!, "Ext");

        if (!Directory.Exists(extensionsIconsFolderPath))
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException($"The Extensions folder was not found at {projectRoot}");
        }

        Files.Clear();

        var filesInDirr = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);

        foreach (var file in filesInDirr)
        {

            string extension = Path.GetExtension(file).ToLower();
            string iconPath = GetIconPathForExtension(extension, extensionsIconsFolderPath);

            Files.Add(new FileItem
            {
                Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                Extention = extension,
                FullPath = Path.GetFullPath(file),
                Icon = iconPath,
            });
        }
    }
}

public async Task DeleteNonMp4files(string folderPath)
{
    IsEnable = false;
    if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
        var filesInFolder = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
        var totalFiles = Files.Count;
        var filesDeleted = 0;


        foreach (var item in filesInFolder)
        {
            if (!Path.GetExtension(item).Equals(".mp4", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                File.Delete(item);
                filesDeleted++;
                Progress = (double)filesDeleted / totalFiles * 100;

                await Task.Delay(50);
            }
        }
        GetFiles(folderPath);

        Progress = 100;

        if (Progress == 100)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
            IsEnable = true;
        }


    }
}

private string GetIconPathForExtension(string extension, string extensionsFolder)
{
    string iconFileName = extension switch
    {
        ".avi" => "avi.png",
        ".mp4" => "mp4.png",
        ".mp3" => "mp3.png",
        ".pdf" => "pdf.png",
        ".png" => "png.png",
        ".txt" => "txt.png",
        ".wav" => "wav.png",
        _ => "question.png",// Fallback icon if no match is found
    };

    // Combine the Extensions folder path with the icon file name
    string iconPath = Path.Combine(extensionsFolder, iconFileName);

    // Check if the icon exists, otherwise return a default icon
    if (!File.Exists(iconPath))
    {
        iconPath = Path.Combine(extensionsFolder, "default.png");  // Fallback to default icon if not found
    }

    return iconPath;
}

partial void OnSelectedItemChanged(FileItem? value)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value!.FullPath))
    {
        var p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = value.FullPath,
            UseShellExecute = true
        });

        Task.Delay(5000);

        Processes!.Add(p!);
    }


}

public void CleanUpProcesses()
{
    foreach (var process in Processes!)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!process.HasExited)
            {
                process.Kill(); // Kill the process
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle errors during cleanup (e.g., process already exited)
            Console.WriteLine($"Error terminating process: {ex.Message}");
        }

I am trying to kill the process when the app is closing and I have already tried with a try-catch block and nothing.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/3456383/1136211, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74093890/1136211

When FileName is aimed to a non-executable file, Process.Start cannot return a process object.
If you know what application the file associated to, you cound set FileName to this application, and set the cmd parameters to the actual file path. Your example could be this:
var p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
  FileName = "MediaPlayer",
  UseShellExecute = true,
  Arguments = value.FullPath,
});


"... a non-executable file, Process.Start cannot return a process object." - this is not true. Start only returns null when no new process was started, i.e. when an already running process opens the file.

reply @Clemens: If the -FilePath is a '.mp3' file, and there is no 'MediaPlayer' process on the machine, it will start a 'MediaPlayer' process. But the process is not started via Process.Start directly.

Try it yourself. Start will then return a Process instance, not null, even when FileName contains the path to e.g. a media file. It will only return null when the associated application is already running. See the answers to the similar questions in the comment on the question. And what exactly is -FilePath supposed to be? The property is called FileName.

@Clemens I try the code in a WPF(.NET framework 4.8) project.  var p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() {     FileName =         @"C:\\test.mp3",     UseShellExecute = true, }); Before running the code, there is no 'MediaPlayer' process on the machine.  After running the code, the '.mp3' file is opened in a new 'MediaPlayer' process. The VS2022 shows that the p is null

@Clemens And I also try the code in .NET8, the behavior of Process.Start is same.

-FilePath is a mistake, because the same API in PS use the argument name. I have correctted the answer

That is not reproducible for me. When I start an mp3 file, the system runs my VLC media player, and Process.Start returns a valid Process instance. And this conforms to the documented behavior.
